# Volley timeout error in android app

Tags: php, android, android-volley, android-logcat

I am developing an application and it should connect to the DB and fetch some numbers from it but whatever I do i am getting volley timeout error and i cannot solve my problem. followings are my code:

android part:

```
public  int digicalculator()
{
    //int digipoints=0;
    // Log.d("ggggggggg","digicallll");
    fetchPoints("hh");
    digipoints = digipoints + 30;
    return digipoints;
}


private void fetchPoints(String email)
{
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "fetch_points";
    Log.d("ggggggggg", "digicallll");

   // Toast.makeText(Pointcalculator.this,"in fetch", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   //   pD.setMessage("Fetching Points ...");
    showDialog(10);

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, AppConfig.URL_FETCH_USER_POINTS, new Response.Listener<String>()
    {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hereee", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse");
            Log.d(TAG, "FETCH RESPONSE: " + response.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //hideDialog(10);

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                // boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                //  if (!error)
                //  {
                // Now store the user in sqlite
                String totalpts = (jObj.getString("totalpoints"));
                String digipts = (jObj.getString("digipoints"));
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "totalpoints : "+totalpts, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "digipoints : "+digipts, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                try
                {
                    totalpoints = Integer.parseInt(totalpts);
                    digipoints = Integer.parseInt(digipts);
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
                {
                    System.out.println("Could not parse " + nfe);
                }


                // Inserting row in users table
                // db.addUser(name, email, uid, created_at);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Points successfully retrieved!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Points retriving Error: " + error.toString());
           // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //hideDialog();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        {
            // Posting params to register url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("email", "hh");



            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}
```

and this is appController :

```
public class AppController extends Application {

public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

private static AppController mInstance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;
}

public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}



public RequestQueue getRequestQueue()
{
    if (mRequestQueue == null)
    {
         mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        Network network = new BasicNetwork(new OkHttpStack());
        mRequestQueue = new RequestQueue(new DiskBasedCache(new File(getCacheDir(), "volley")), network);
        mRequestQueue.start();
    }

    return mRequestQueue;
}
public class OkHttpStack extends HurlStack {
    private final OkUrlFactory mFactory;

    public OkHttpStack() {
        this(new OkHttpClient());
    }


    private  OkHttpClient getUnsafeOkHttpClient()
    {
        try {
            // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
            final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]
                    {
                            new X509TrustManager() {
                                @Override
                                public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {}

                                @Override
                                public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {}

                                @Override
                                public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                                    return null;
                                }
                            }
                    };

            // Install the all-trusting trust manager
            final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            // Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
            final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
            okHttpClient.setSslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
            okHttpClient.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }
            });

            return okHttpClient;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }




    public OkHttpStack(OkHttpClient client)
    {
        client=getUnsafeOkHttpClient();
        if (client == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Client must not be null.");
        }
        mFactory = new OkUrlFactory(client);
    }

    @Override
    protected HttpURLConnection createConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
        return mFactory.open(url);
    }
}


public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
    req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    req.setTag(TAG);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
    if (mRequestQueue != null) {
        mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
    }
}
```

}

and this is my php code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
 $username = "**";
 $password = "**";
 $dbname = "**";
    $con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
mysqli_connect_error();
}
    if (isset($_POST['email'])) 
    {
    // receiving the post params
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $sql="select totalpoints , digipoints from users where email='$email'";
    $result = $con->query($sql);
    }
$row = $result -> fetch_assoc();
while($row)
    {
        $totalpoints = $row["totalpoints"];
                $digipoints = $row["digipoints"];
    }
    print(json_encode($totalpoints, $digipoints));
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

and this is my android studio logcat:

```
    01-23 07:05:51.135  13653-13678/com.example.neshat.test D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
01-23 07:05:51.142  13653-13678/com.example.neshat.test D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa42f1b40, tid 13678
01-23 07:05:51.152  13653-13678/com.example.neshat.test I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-23 07:05:51.180  13653-13678/com.example.neshat.test D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
01-23 07:05:51.199  13653-13678/com.example.neshat.test W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-23 07:05:51.199  13653-13678/com.example.neshat.test W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa3606320, error=EGL_SUCCESS
01-23 07:05:51.250  13653-13678/com.example.neshat.test W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-23 07:05:51.250  13653-13678/com.example.neshat.test W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa3606340, error=EGL_SUCCESS
01-23 07:05:59.917  13653-13653/com.example.neshat.test E/this﹕ Points retriving Error: com.android.volley.TimeoutError
01-23 07:05:59.918  13653-13653/com.example.neshat.test D/Volley﹕ [1] Request.finish: 8850 ms: [ ] http://beeken.hevak.net/fetchPointsfromDB.php 0xc87d15d6 NORMAL 1
```

Comment: your server is ok and responding to pings, so thats ok-- check your PHP/apache error log file. any errors for your PHP script will be there

Comment: and also, you are doing a String Request. any reason why you json encoding from PHP. You can do (eho $totalpoints."#".$digipoints;) and split the string at the other end for (#) character

Comment: [23-Jan-2016 12:25:15 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 90 seconds exceeded in /home/hevak/public_html/beeken/fetchPointsfromDB.php on line 27
 this is my error log @Tasos

Comment: yeah, looks like this line (print(json_encode($totalpoints, $digipoints));). Im i right? your script is hanging and exceeding the max exec time set in the PHP settings

Comment: you mean I should just replace the print jason_encode with echo?? @Tasos

Comment: i never tried print -- i always use echo and the string when im making a volley string request -- when im making a  volley JSON request i echo json from php. so try what i put in my comment.

Comment: by the way, is this (select totalpoints , digipoints from users where email='$email) pulling a lot of data from the table or just one row. If you are pulling a lot its better if  you do a Voley Json Request instead of string -- http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Comment: uhum, I did that and timeout is not happening. although i have other errors to work on. thank u @Tasos

Comment: you get there in the end :)